# Parse html with angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html-table, html-parsing

How do I parse HTML with AngularJS? I have tried to build an filter like this:

```
gameApp.filter('unsafe', function($sce) {
    return function(val) {
        return $sce.trustAsHtml(val);
    };
});
```

I use it like this in my view:

```
<div ng-controller="gameCtrl">
    <table>
        <p ng-bind-html="result | unsafe"></p>
    </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

But that don't work. result contains tr and td tags that I want to fill my table with.

Here is my controller:

```
var gameApp = angular.module("gameApp", ['ngRoute']);

gameApp.service('link', function() {
    this.user = false;
});
gameApp.filter('unsafe', function($sce) {
    return function(val) {
        return $sce.trustAsHtml(val);
    };
});

function makeTableFrom(str) {
    var k = 1;
    result = "";

    for(var i = 1; i <= 8; i++) {
        result += '<tr>';

        for(var j = 1; j <= 20; j++) {
            if(str[k] === '#') {
                result += '<td id=' + k + '">#</td>';
            }
            else if(str[k] === '&') {
                result += '<td class="click" val="water" id="' + k + '">&</td>';
            }
            else {
                result += '<td class="click" id="' + k + '"><a href="#"></a></td>';
            }

            k++;
        }
        result += '</tr>';
    }
    return result;
}


gameApp.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider

    .when('/', {
            templateUrl : 'partials/firstpage.html',
            controller  : 'firstPageCtrl'
    })

    .when('/game', {
            templateUrl : 'partials/game.html',
            controller  : 'gameCtrl'
    });

});

gameApp.controller("firstPageCtrl", function($scope,$http,link,$location) {
    $scope.doLogin = function() {
        $http.post("lib/action.php", {username: $scope.username, password: $scope.password}).success(function(data) {
            if(data) {
                link.user = data;
                console.log(link.user);
                $location.path("/game");
            }
        }).error(function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        });
    };
});


gameApp.controller("gameCtrl", function($scope,$http,link,$location) {
    //$scope.trr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8];
    //$scope.tdd = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20];
    $scope.getMonsters = "1";
    var map;

    $http.post("lib/action.php", {monsters: $scope.getMonsters}).success(function(data) {
        map = data;
        console.log(map);
        $scope.result = makeTableFrom(data);
        console.log($scope.result);
    });

    if(link.user) {
        /*$scope.message = "fisk";
        console.log(link.user);*/
    } else {
        /*$scope.message = "Ledsen fisk";
        console.log("Är inte satt");*/
    }
});
```

Anyone who can help me?

Comment: You should learn HTML first, then you can venture into something advanced like javascript and angular afterwards.

Comment: A small note : Think you need a `var` before `result = "";` or just `var k = 1, result = "";`

Comment: i think you need to add ng-sanitize module

Comment: @Brunis: Learn HTML. Are you serious? I will take a look at ng-sanitize.

Comment: @user500468 very much so, look at that invalid junk you posted!

Comment: @Brunis: Invalid junk?

Comment: @user500468 in how many ways do you need it explained? Your HTML is invalid!

Comment: It would serve your interests to go through a few angular tutorials, because it has the power to do what you're trying to do manually with javascript.

Comment: go through this and learn to use the ng-repeat directive, that is what you need to replace all that javascript with a few simple lines of html. https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_02 Yes, it is that simple!

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, you would use templates or views to show HTML and pass data to those.  Aside from live code editors, displaying raw HTML opens XSS and other security vulnerabilities.